# Stripe - Iam getting stripe error in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm working with stripe checkout, in Nextjs 13+ version, Iam getting error like this:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {message, name, code, config, request, response}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

[orderId]/payWithStripe/route.ts:

```
import Order from "@/models/order";
import connect from "@/utils/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
export const POST = async (
  req: Request,
  { params, searchParams }: { params: any; searchParams: any }
) => {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const { amount, id, productDetails } = body;
    const { orderId } = params;
    const line_items = productDetails.map((item: any) => {
      return {
        price_data: {
          currency: "inr",
          product_data: {
            name: item.name,
            images: [item.image],
          },
          unit_amount: Math.round(amount * 100), // Amount in cents
        },
        quantity: item.qty,
      };
    });
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items,
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: `http://localhost:3000/order/${orderId}/success`,
      // http://localhost:3000/order/${orderId}/success
      cancel_url: `http://localhost:3000/order/${orderId}`,
    });
    await connect();

    const order = await Order.findById(orderId);
    const sessionId = session.id;
    const retrieveSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sessionId);
    console.log("payment_status", retrieveSession.payment_status);

    if (retrieveSession.payment_status == "paid") {
      order.isPaid = true;
      order.paidAt = Date.now();
      await order.save();
      return NextResponse.json({ success: true, sessionUrl: session.url });
    } else {
      order.isPaid = false;
      await order.save();
      return NextResponse.json({ message: `Payment failed.` }, { status: 400 });
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    return new NextResponse(`${error}`, {
      status: 500,
      statusText: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Frontend/

```
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Form = ({
  total,
  order_id,
  stripePromise,
  productDetails,
}: {
  total: any;
  order_id: any;
  stripePromise: any;
  productDetails: any;
}) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>("");
  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const stripe = await stripePromise;

    if (!error) {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(`/api/order/${order_id}/payWithStripe`, {
          amount: total,
          productDetails,
        });
        if (res.data.sessionUrl) {
          window.location.href = res.data.sessionUrl;
        }
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error);
      }
    } else {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="stripe">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="bg-black w-full text-white h-[65px] rounded-md"
        >
          PAY WITH STRIPE
        </button>

        {error && <span className="p-0 ">{error}</span>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Since it was logging `payment_status` as `unpaid` at first, so it was working, then why it was throwing error?

I'm getting this error since from morning, at last, I met you. **PLEASE IGNORE IT IF YOU THINK THIS IS STUPID, IT'S A NEWBIE MISTAKE :)**

Answer (score 2):

Your `error` state variable is not very consistent, it can be a string or an object.
For now I'd probably suggest just doing `<span className="p-0 ">{JSON.stringify(error)}</span>` so you can at least see the details of the error.

Comment: "message":"Request failed with status code 400",

Comment: I think the error is here: if(retrieveSession.payment_status == "paid") any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe look at the Network tab in the devtools of your browser and see what your server returns when `/api/order` is called. Maybe check your Stripe API logs at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs.